# when closing google marker go back to center of map

Tags: google-maps

I have a map which opens multiple markers then when you click on one of the markers a street view of that location opens up. What Im trying to do is when you close the marker have it re-center the map

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the center of a map (`getCenter()`), so you will know the lat/long before you open a Street View image.  There are then `setCenter()` and `panTo()` methods in the API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Comment: What do you mean by 'marker'? If you mean an infoWindow (such as the 'balloon' which appears when you click on the marker in [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.html), then I'm not quite sure I understand your problem.  You'll have to provide more info for us to help you more.